# find the value $2^n\equiv ?\pmod {12}$

Tags: number-theory

if $n>1$ odd number,find $$2^n\equiv ?\pmod {12}$$

it seem the answer is $8$,because
$$2^3=8\equiv 8\pmod{12}$$
$$2^5=32\equiv 8\pmod {12}$$
$$2^7=128\equiv 8\pmod {12}$$
$$2^9=512\equiv 8\pmod {12}$$
$$\cdots $$
But How to prove it for all postive integers $n$?

Comment: $4 \cdot 8 = 32 = 24 + 8 \equiv 8 \pmod{12}$

Answer (score 4):

To be precise, we want to prove that if $n$ is an odd number $\geq 3$, then $$2^n\equiv 8\pmod{12}.$$
Since you've verify the initial case $n=3$, we assume if $k\geq3$ is an odd number and $2^k\equiv 8\pmod{12}$ holds, then $$2^{k+2}\equiv 8\times 4\equiv 32\equiv 8\pmod{12}$$
holds as well. Hence we completed the proof by induction.

Comment: For quite a while I was trying to do this without induction, but this really is nice, short, and sweet.

Comment: @Randall We can reduce the induction to the *triviality* $\,1^n\equiv 1\,$  by factoring out $4$ (or $8)$ as I explain in my answer and its comments. Using this mod distributivity often simplifies modular arithmetic (it can be viewed as an *operational* form of CRT more amenable to computation).

Answer (score 2):

$8\cdot 4^{\large n}\!\bmod 12\, =\, 4(2\cdot 4^{\large n}\! \bmod 3)\, =\, 4(2)$

Comment: $\large {\rm By}\ \ ab\bmod ac = a(b\bmod c) = $ [mod Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242), and 4 = 1 (mod 3) $\ \ $

Comment: **Or** $\,\large 8\cdot 4^{\large n}\!\bmod 24\, =\, 8(\color{#c00}4^{\large n}\! \bmod 3)\, =\, 8(1)\,$ more generally, by $\,\large \color{#c00}4^n\equiv \color{#c00}1^n\equiv 1\pmod{\!3}.\ $ Notice that factoring out the $\,8\,$   simplifies the induction to a *completely trivial* instance: $\,\,\large 1^n\equiv 1\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

You can prove it with the Chinese remainder theorem: $12=2^2\cdot3$.

We have $2^n\cong0\pmod{2^2}$, and$2^n\cong2\pmod3$ ( since by Fermat's little theorem, $2^2\cong1\pmod3$).

Using Bezout's identity,  $1\cdot2^2-1\cdot 3=1$, we get $2\cdot1\cdot2^2+0\cdot1\cdot 3=8$, as our solution.

Comment: A slicker way to apply CRT here is via mod distributivity - see my answer.

Comment: Nice @BillDubuque.  I will try to use it some time.

Answer (score 0):

We first calculate $$2^n \mod{3}, 2^n \mod{4}$$
and then combine the results with Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Both should be easy to calculate.
Writing n=2k+1, $$2^{2k+1} \equiv {-1}^{2k+1} \equiv ({-1}^{2})^{k} \times {-1}^1 \equiv 1 \times -1 \equiv -1 \equiv 2 \mod{3}$$
$$2^{2k+1} \equiv 4^k\times2\equiv0\mod{4}$$
Therefore by CRT, $$2^{2k+1} \equiv 8 \mod{12}$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that:

$$2^{2m+1}-8=2(2^m+2)(2^m-2)$$

We wish to show the RHS is a multiple of $12$. The outside $2$ means we need one of the brackets to be a multiple of $6$. Can you show that if two even numbers are four apart, one of them must be a multiple of $6$?